# Why isn't the template argument deduced?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using `istream_iterator` to insert contents from my file. I use the `std::copy` algorithm too.

So we know `istream_iterator` takes a stream as an argument:

```
std::istream_iterator<int> it = file;
```

I can just pass the stream but why here doesn't it work?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("in.txt");
    std::vector<int> v;

    std::copy(infile, std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(v));
}
```

I have to do it like this:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(infile), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

But this looks very verbose and I feel like they're a better way to do what I'm doing...

Comment: @juanchopanza `infile` but I made a typo.

Comment: A call to a function template doesn't perform implicit user-defined conversions of arguments. `std::copy` is a function template, and stream-to-iterator is a user-defined conversion.

Comment: This is one of many downsides of C++ standard library using iterators instead of ranges. Everybody kind of knows it by now but it's difficult to change everything now with so much code already out there.

Comment: @JanHudec Adding overloads like `std::copy(std::basic_istream<T>, OutputIt)` wouldn't really break code. And how much would they simplify code.

Comment: @leemes: With istream it's really a corner case. And it's not obvious what you want to extract as you can extract many things from istream (no, it does not have to be the type of the container; you might want the copy to do implicit conversion too).

Comment: @leemes: But [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) helps quite a lot.

Comment: @JanHudec Exactly that is what I mean: why aren't there overloads in std `<algorithm>` for "ranges"? (Where "ranges" are another concept with `.begin()`, `.end()`, `value_type` etc.) [Something like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003627/stl-algorithms-why-no-additional-interface-for-containers-additional-to-iterat) And then for streams we could add a range wrapper rather than an iterator wrapper: `copy(istream_reader<int>(infile), back_inserter(v))` This would be so helpful.

Comment: @leemes: You can get exactly that from the Boost.Range. It's not in standard library because it takes ages for a committee to agree on something. Most of the time they are only agreeing on things already tested too, usually in boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what `std::copy` expects from the object being passed. The algorithm `std::copy` expects iterators to operate on. To be more precise, the first two arguments have to be "InputIterator"s to read from (start and end), that is, the two objects have to satisfy [some "concept"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).

Sadly, IO streams in C++ don't fulfill the InputIterator concept automatically (also, an end iterator would still be missing), but only if you *wrap* them in an instance of `std::istream_iterator<T>`, while the end iterator is symbolically defined using an instance without pointing to a stream.

You could wrap around `std::copy` which accepts an input stream instead of two iterators (so this also eliminates the need to name the end iterator):

```
template <class T,
          class OutputIt /* deduced */,
          class CharT    /* deduced */>
OutputIt  copy_from_istream(std::basic_istream<CharT> & stream, OutputIt out) {
    return std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<T, CharT>(stream),
        std::istream_iterator<T>(),
        out
    );  
}
```

Using this is now very simple:

```
copy_from_istream<int>(infile, std::back_inserter(v));
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/YGUw47)

Answer (score 1):

This is how the relevant overload of [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is declared:

> ```
> template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
> OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
> ```

This function is templatized and it will deduce the type by the argument given. In your case, the first argument is of type `std::basic_ifstream<...>`, so since the second argument didn't match, you get a compile time error.

That's why you need to be explicit with the type. The compiler won't know what you mean otherwise.

A shorter way of doing this would be to provide the actual template argument explicitly:

```
v.assign<std::istream_iterator<int>>(infile, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vector::assign()` instead of `copy()` algorithm:

```
v.assign(std::istream_iterator<int>(infile), std::istream_iterator<int>())
```