# STL Extension/Modification Best Practice

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I have been writing in c++ for a few months, and i am comfortable enough with it now to begin implementing my own library, consisting of things that i have found myself reusing again and again. One thing that nagged me was the fact that you always had to provide a beginning and end iterator for functions like `std::accumulate`,`std::fill` etc...

The option to provide a qualified container was completely absent and it was simply an annoyance to write begin and end over and over. So, I decided to add this functionality to my library, but i came across problem, i couldn't figure out the best approach of doing so. Here were my general solutions:

**1. Macros**  
        - A macro that encapsulates an entire function call
              ex. `QUICK_STL(FCall)`  
        - A macro that takes the container, function name, and optional args
              ex. `QUICK_STL(C,F,Args...)`

**2. Wrapper Function/Functor** 
        - A class that takes the container, function name, and optional args
              ex. `quick_stl(F, C, Args...)`

**3. Overload Functions**
        - Overload every function in namespace `std` OR my library namespace
ex

```
namespace std { // or my library root namespace 'cherry' 
    template <typename C, typename T>
    decltype(auto) count(const C& container, const T& value);
}
```

I usually steer clear of macros, but in this case it could certainty save *alot*
of lines of code from being written. With regards to function overloading, every single function that i want to use i must overload, which wouldn't really scale. The upside to that approach though is that you retain the names of the functions. With perfect forwarding and `decltype(auto)` overloading becomes alot easier, but still will take time to implement, and would have to be modified if ever another function was added. As to whether or not i should overload the `std` namespace i am rather skeptical on whether or not it would be appropriate in this case.

*What would be the most appropriate way of going about overloading functions in the STD namespace (note these functions will only serve as proxy's to the original functions)?*

Comment: _I usually steer clear of macros_ **Ah, good...**  _but in this case it could certainty save alot of lines of code from being written._ **Nooooo!!! It's a trap!!!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this: [Why do all  functions take only ranges, not containers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231336/why-do-all-algorithm-functions-take-only-ranges-not-containers)

And This: [STL algorithms: Why no additional interface for containers (additional to iterator pairs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003627/stl-algorithms-why-no-additional-interface-for-containers-additional-to-iterat)

> I have been writing in c++ for a **few months**, and i am comfortable
>   enough with it now to begin implementing my own library...

Let me look on the brighter side and just say... Some of us have been there before.... :-)

> One thing that nagged me was the fact that you always had to provide a
>   beginning and end iterator for functions like
>   std::accumulate,std::fill etc...

That's why you have [Boost.Ranges](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) and the Eric's proposed [ranges](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) that seems like it isn't gonna make it to C++17.

> 1. Macros

See [Macros](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-vs-macros)

> 2. Wrapper Function/Functor

Not too bad...Provided you do it correctly, You can do that, that's what essentially Ranges do for Containers... See the aforementioned implementations

> 3. Overload Functions
>
>    - Overload every function in namespace `std` ...

Don't do that... The C++ standard doesn't like it.

See what the standard has to say

> [**$17.6.4.2.1**](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.constraints#namespace.std-1) The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within
>   namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template
>   specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only
>   if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the
>   specialization meets the standard library requirements for the
>   original template and is not explicitly prohibited.